# Make chainmail background theme

Tags: css, background, css-gradients

I'd like to make a chainmail like this:

[image: chainmail background theme]

I've tried using linear-gradient but it seems not to work

```css
    background: linear-gradient(#0c0c0c, #222222)!important
```

I expect the output to be like on shown image from imgur. Will linear-gradient work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `radial-gradient`

I used different colors so we can better see the result:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    radial-gradient(50% 100%,#000 35%,transparent 50%) 0   0  /10px 10px,
    radial-gradient(50% 100%,#000 35%,transparent 50%) 5px 5px/10px 10px,
    yellow;
}
```

You can easily adjust the different values to control the size:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    radial-gradient(50% 100%,#000 25%,transparent 50%) 0   0  /8px 8px,
    radial-gradient(50% 100%,#000 25%,transparent 50%) 4px 4px/8px 8px,
    yellow;
}
```